# How to fix post data that return NaN for type numbrer and don't return value for string type in mongodb?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi Everyone I am facing this error when sending post request to the backend, the problem is that when sending data I am not getting the value for name and eamil. And also for phone and passport I am getting NAN as you can see in the screen shoot. I tried several solution online and could not help me. In the backend when I try to post data to my database it works fine. Here are my codes:

**PostForm.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function CreateCustomer() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("");
  const [passNumber, setPassNumber] = useState("");
  const [booked, setBooked] = useState(false);

  const onChangeName = (e) => {
    setName({ name: e.target.value });
  };
  const onChangeEmail = (e) => {
    setEmail({ email: e.target.value });
  };
  const onChangePhone = (e) => {
    setPhoneNumber({ phoneNumber: e.target.value });
  };
  const onChangePassport = (e) => {
    setPassNumber({ passNumber: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const bookingData = {
      name: "name",
      email: "email",
      phone: parseFloat("phone"),
  passport: parseInt("passport"),
    };
    console.log(bookingData);

    await axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/customers/create_customer", bookingData)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);

        setName(name);
        setEmail(email);
        setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        setPassNumber(passNumber);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    setBooked(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {booked ? (
        <p className="bookedMsg">Your room was booked successfully!!!</p>
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="form contact-form">
          <div className="input-group-wrap">
            <div className="input-group">
              <input
                className="input"
                type="text"
                onChange={onChangeName}
                placeholder="Name..."
                required
              />
              <span className="bar"></span>
            </div>
            <div className="input-group">
              <input
                className="input"
                type="email"
                onChange={onChangeEmail}
                placeholder="Email..."
                required
              />
              <span className="bar"></span>
            </div>
            <div className="input-group">
              <input
                onChange={onChangePhone}
                type="number"
                pattern="^\d{10}$"
                className="input"
                placeholder="PhoneNumber..."
                required
              />
              <span className="bar"></span>
            </div>
            <div className="input-group">
              <input
                onChange={onChangePassport}
                type="number"
                className="input"
                placeholder="PassNumber..."
                required
              />
              <span className="bar"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn form-btn btn-purple">
            BOOK NOW
            <span className="dots">
              <i className="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
            </span>
          </button>
        </form>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**CustomerModel.js:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const CustomerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  phoneNumber: {
    type: Number,
    require: true,
  },
  passNumber: {
    type: Number,
    require: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Customers", CustomerSchema);
```

**customerRoute.js:**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Customer = require("../models/Customer");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const customer = await Customer.find();
    res.json(customer);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});

router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const customer = await Customer.findById(req.params.id);
    res.json(customer);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});

router.post("/create_customer", async (req, res) => {
  const customer = new Customer({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
    passNumber: req.body.passNumber,
  });
  try {
    const savedCustomer = await customer.save();
    res.json(savedCustomer);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});

router.patch("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const updatedCustomer = await Customer.updateOne(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      { $set: { name: req.body.name } }
    );
    res.json(updatedCustomer);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});

router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const removedCustomer = await Customer.remove({ _id: req.params.id });
    res.json(removedCustomer);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

[image]

Comment: Typically, a phone number will contain white spaces or slashes, but your data model expects it to be a number. You can't convert a string containing a white space to a number. You should change the type to string in your model or clean your data first, ie remove all non-digit characters

Comment: Hi @derpirscher, thanks for your feedback. I just change the data type to string in my model, but I am getting the same result. do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is with this area.

```
const bookingData = {
      name: "name",
      email: "email",
      phone: parseFloat("phone"),
     passport: parseInt("passport"),
 };
```

You say

> the problem is that when sending data I am not getting the value for
> name and eamil.

If you are trying to get the value of the input you are not set up for it because you literally use "name" in quotes as a value. You have to get the value of input by doing something like this `e.currentTarget.value`. I think you need to learn how to get the actual values by input and attach it to the data obj you want to send to the server.

**You are just using strings not the values of the input**

Now I see you have some `useState` set up. Did you try to get the value from the states? Maybe something like this.

```
const bookingData = {
      name,
      email,
      phone : phoneNumber, //inconsistency with variable names
     passport,
 };
```

Comment: thanks Jack blank, I am getting the values now, but all the validation fall. This the error: message: "Customers validation failed: name: Cast to string failed for value "{ name: 'emma' }" at path "name" for each input value.